# how to consume from all partitions in two service instances in kafka with spring cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud

Background is:

I want to trigger the websocket client when kafka message is received.
With two instances of websocket server this produce a problem that kafka partition does not have to be correlated with server instance serving exact websocket client.

Kafka topic is already filled in with messages with multiple partitions.
I'm not interested in resetting offsets and real 'commit log as source of truth'.
For this case kafka is used just to pass trigger to web socket client

What i need:

My intention is to bypass the natural partitioning withing the same consumer group.
I would like to receive messages from all partitions on all instances of same group id. So i want duplicates.
I use spring cloud on top of kafka.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to receive messages from all partitions on all instances of same group id.

That's not possible. You would need unique groups for each consumer instance to get all partitions to be consumed.

Comment: thanks. so it seems the proper way to go is to have anonymous/generated groups.